# c++ operator overloading << on Array pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two classes, `Pony` and `Bear` which inherits from an `Animal` Abstract Class.

I have made an `Animal` Array which contains one `Pony` and one `Bear` :

```
Animal **arr = new Animal * [2];
arr[0] = new Pony("pony name");
arr[1] = new Bear("bear name");
```

The argument to Pony and Bear is it name. I then want to print the Animal name by ovearloading the `<<` operator. something like

```
cout << arr[0];  // Print something like : "I am Pony/Bear Name !"
```

But my test to overload fail... I try to do something like

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& os, Animal &a);
```

But It do not detect the overload when I compile...

How is it possible to overload the `<<` operator in my array of pointers ?

Full error after the test `*arr[0]`

```
main.cpp: In function ‘Object** MyUnitTests()’:
main.cpp:20:22: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << * * obj’
main.cpp:20:22: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40:0,
             from Object.hh:14,
             from main.cpp:11:
```

And then 200 lines of errors comming from std::cout (they disapears if I remove the * on the arr[0]).

Comment: What is the type of `arr[0]`?

Comment: Its an array of pointers so `cout << arr[0];` will print the pointer dir, jus try `cout << *arr[0];`

Comment: Don't take `a` by non-const reference. If you're changing it, don't.

Comment: arr[0] is a pointer on a Pony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[0]` is a pointer, so you'll need to perform indirection to be able to pass it to that `operator<<` overload:

```
cout << *arr[0];
```

You're using `new` much more than you should be. I'll let you off with the animals themselves because you need polymorphism (although you should use smart pointers instead), but the array of pointers does not need to be dynamically allocated:

```
Animal* arr[2];
```

Comment: I have already try your code and it tells me `no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << * * arr`

Comment: @JérémyPouyet Looks like you have two asterisks there.

Comment: This message appears when I do `cout << *arr[0]`. What would your operator<< prototype ?

Comment: @JérémyPouyet Okay, I don't believe that the error matches the code you gave before. Can you give the source of `main.cpp`?